# Профессионалы в русском языке – а какие у них профессии? Всегда ли профессионал знает больше, чем любитель?

Tags: обсуждение

**Из словаря**

**ПРОФЕССИОНАЛ**. Тот, кто сделал какое-л. занятие, деятельность своей профессией. Охотник-профессионал. // **Хороший специалист**. В автоделе это настоящий п.

**ДИЛЕТАНТ**,  1. Тот, кто занимается чем-л., не имея специальной подготовки, систематических знаний; любитель. Д. в морском деле, в филологии. 2. Неодобр. О ком-л., **плохо разбирающемся в чём-л.** Отвергнуть суждения дилетантов.

**Человек окончил вуз –  и сразу стал профессионалом?**  А  если он «купил» диплом (заплатил за курсовые, рефераты и т.д.), то тоже профессионал? Или вот какая история: на 5-ом курсе педагогического университета вдруг выясняется, что студенты совершенно безграмотны, а орфографии и пунктуации их не учили, считали, что и так знают (но зато проходили фонологические школы, правда, еще на первом курсе, никто уже ничего не помнит).

**Но  есть же  и достойные учителя:** они честно  получили свой красный диплом, честно двадцать  лет отработали в школе, уж они-то точно всё знают – настоящие профессионалы! Ну да, знают методику обучения, знают стандартный курс русского языка. Но ведь двадцать лет  прошло, наука не стоит на месте, а когда им при их загруженности следить за новейшими открытиями.

**А вот дилетант – человек свободный, времени у него – не мерено!** К тому же еще одно преимущество есть у дилетанта – это незаштампованные могзи, открытость мышления. Нет у него авторитетов, а есть над ним огромное пространство, куда и устремляется его свободная мысль.

**Итак, вот они перед вами – профессионал и дилетант.** Кому вы доверяете, кому оказываете все знаки почтения, а в кого бросите камень при первой возможности?   Ответ вроде бы ясен, и тем не менее,  всегда ли профессионал знает больше, чем любитель?

Comment: А при чём тут технические проблемы и модерирование форума? Где-то встречается фраза про профессионалов?

Comment: Вопрос касается поведения участников форума, которые выделяют профессионалов, считают их ответы безупречными и пренебрежительно относятся к так называемым любителям (или дилетантам). Стоит ли приветствовать такое поведение или оно недопустимо?  Мы здесь одинаковые, мы из одной команды или у нас разный статус? Ты не профессионал, поэтому твое мнение мало чего стоит - об этом  в открытую можно сказать участнику форума?

Comment: *Мы здесь одинаковые, мы из одной команды или у нас разный статус?* - Мы здесь неодинаковые, что видно из ответов. *Ты не профессионал, поэтому твое мнение мало чего стоит - об этом в открытую можно сказать участнику форума?* Почему бы нет? Например, если участник копирует данные из учебников и справочников, то всё нормально, а если он пытается высказываться "от себя", то это сразу же выдает в нем дилетанта -- так почему бы ему об этом и не сказать? Если уж он сам не чувствует...

Comment: Диалог: Это что за форум? - Это форум копирайтеров, подбираем тексты с ответами. Кому хорошие ответы из учебников и справочников? - А что, любые ответы есть? -  Не любые, не любые, только из учебников и справочников! - В справочниках я и сам найду. - Ну так ищи сам, ходят тут всякие умники, работать мешают.  Кому хорошие ответы из учебников и справочников!  Только из учебников и справочников!

Answer (score 4):

На данном форуме приветствуются любые участники и профессионалы и любители, главное, чтобы они адекватно оценивали степень своей компетентности. Самый высокий рейтинг на форуме у behemothus'а, который себя к профессионалам не относит, но тем не менее, по-моему мнению, вполне таковым является.

Как я уже писал важно лишь понимать, в чём ты разбираешься, а в чём нет. На этом форуме, например, я ставил минусы ответам, верным с точки зрения русского языка, но дающим искажённое представление об истории (по образованию я историк), однако я не рискну лезть в вопросы, касающиеся сложных вопросов пунктуации и помощи с аргументами в ЕГЭ, так как не разбираюсь в этих вопросах.

Главное же оставаться взаимовежливыми, даже если точки зрения на какой-либо вопрос у вас расходятся.

Comment: Обычно участники форума любят оценивать степень чужой компетентности, и отношения друг к другу весьма далеки от взаимовежливых.   Это очень большой недостаток форума,  мешает работе, не способствует повышению авторитета ресурса. Мне кажется, модераторы должны строже отслеживать такие факты.  А вот чем измерить профессионализм в русском языке, я так и не знаю, не могу определить критерий. И рейтинг здесь не показатель, достаточно иметь хорошую группу поддержки.  В других профессиях, наверное, это легче  сделать.

Comment: @Sibylla если вы считаете, что сообщение нарушает правила сайта, обязательно отмечайте его тревогой. В этом случае модераторы проверят информацию и примут необходимые меры.

Comment: В целом поддерживаю, только это не форум :)

Comment: *А вот чем измерить профессионализм в русском языке, я так и не знаю, не могу определить критерий* А и не надо теоретически определять, по ответам же сразу видно. Важно самому осознавать, что ты дилетант, и не слишком часто высказываться "от себя". А если уж высказался, то добавлять "имхо".

Comment: Однажды некий господин N проснулся и осознал, что он дилетант. Это было шестое чувство, уж точно не четвертое и не пятое. Он ясно ощущал невидимый мир и другие измерения. Кто-то в другом измерении сказал ему: "Ты - дилетант! Осознаешь или нет?" - "Да, - испуганно прошептал N, - осознаю".  Тут связь  прервалась,  но "осознание" осталось. И теперь  N твердит постоянно: "Важно самому осознавать, что ты дилетант".

Answer (score 0):

> > А вот дилетант – человек свободный, времени у него – не мерено! К тому же еще одно преимущество есть у дилетанта – это незаштампованные могзи, открытость мышления. Нет у него авторитетов, а есть над ним огромное пространство, куда и устремляется его свободная мысль.

Ужас какой... Это вы серьезно? Представляете такое, например, в физике или вообще в технике? Там такого агрессивного дилетанта сразу поставят на место. А тут всё субъективно и поэтому всё можно?

Про таких "свободных людей" хорошо говорит Зализняк: все мнения имеют право на существование, но из этого не следует, что все они одинаково ценны. Как говорится, ни прибавить ни убавить.

Comment: Забудем о физике и технике, мы не строим самолеты и не водим поезда, но мы все говорим на русском языке. Так кто здесь важнее, кто больший специалист: ученый-филолог или, к примеру,  писатель-классик? Кто создал современный литературный язык? Александр Сергеевич Пушкин.  А вот что известный специалист-филолог Виноградов В.В. говорит о том, как Пушкин относился к грамматике: "Грамматика представлялась Пушкину теми оковами живого национально-языкового сознания, которые регулируют и ограничивают свободное движение поэта в сфере языка, но которые писатель не имеет права совсем с себя сбросить".

Comment: В  наше время специалистами можно считать людей, профессионально занимающихся лингвистикой, тех, кто пишет учебники для вузов, научные труды по конкретным темам и т..д., но вряд ли они заходят на наш форум.  А учитель в школе - это специалист? Да, но не по той части, учитель - это методист, он не изучает предмет как науку, он специализируется на методах передачи знаний другим. К тому же он так загружен, что вряд ли у него остается время на ознакомление с современной наукой о языке, у любителя для этого больше времени, да и интереса тоже.

Comment: Поэтому не надо здесь противопоставлять любителей и "профессионалов", если только вопрос не касается методов обучения русскому языку в школе, школьных программ и др.

Comment: Ууу, вы заговорили штампами. "Кто создал современный литературный язык? Александр Сергеевич Пушкин". Это красивая фраза, так говорят, но надо ж понимать, что, мягко говоря, это не совсем так.

Comment: Это я к тому, кто лучше знает язык - писатель с мировым именем или  вчерашний выпускник педвуза (без красного диплома).  Кто из них профессионал - можете сказать? Или они оба не профессионалы?

Comment: И при чем здесь писатель с мировым именем?

Comment: Писатель - профессия. Он - профессионал, или кто? Просто перечислите.

Comment: Среди нас нет писателей с мировыми именами, зачем эти теории? А профессионала и дилетанта видно по ответу, если он более-менее развернутый.

Comment: Видно - это не ответ, это ваши субъективные ощущения, которые Вы даже  не можете обозначить словами . Вряд ли такие ответы имеют какую-либо ценность.

Comment: Вот вам еще очень наглядный пример. В главной ветке сейчас идёт тёрка насчёт "где" и "в котором". Видели? Если нет, полюбуйтесь. Синонимы ли это и каковы нюансы различий? Дилетанты ужжжасно хотят выглядеть профессионалами и выдают длиннейшие и никчёмные посты. Им невдомёк,что профессионализм-то совсем не в этом. Но... настоящий профессионализм недоступен, а "выглядеть" ужасно хочется.

Comment: Забавно, как наши уважаемые господа модераторы Aer и Morkovkin помогают друг другу "быть профессионалами". Вот г-н Aer задал умнейший вопрос про дополнение, а г-н Morkovkin нагуглил, добавил пару фраз от себя и вставил ответ. Ни дать ни взять профессионал! Скоро они поменяются ролями, следите ))

Comment: Наверное, вы должны их разоблачить, особенно если поменяются.

Comment: Дык забанят ведь, они же жуть какие обидчивые и злопамятные ))

Comment: @Niemand если у вас есть какие-то вопросы по модерированию, вы можете задать их на Месте без каких либо санкций.